# Major images conundrum - Node.js Express server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, image, cloudinary

So we have a backend facility with Node.js that scrapes an HTML webpage for img tags. We do this with a worker child_process so as not to block the main process. The reason we do this on the server is because we have CORS issues when trying to access HTML pages using AJAX / with Angular $http.

When the backend web scraper is done, it could send a list of urls to the browser. The browser could make AJAX requests for the images that pertain to those urls, but to my knowledge, the front-end would experience the same CORS issues that it would with retrieving HTML.

So we currently have a fairly crappy solution to this problem. We use Cloudinary to do the heavy lifting instead of our Node.js server handling base64. The backend worker child_process scrapes the HTML, gets the image urls, and then sends a request to Cloudinary to retrieve the images and send back our server the new Cloudinary urls. Then we send the Cloudinary urls to the front-end and the front-end can access those Cloudinary urls without any CORS issues.

There are two problems with this:

> 1. This is fairly slow - scraping takes about 2 seconds and then waiting for Cloudinary to save the images and respond is another 2-4
>      seconds. So the browser has to wait for about 4-6 seconds.
> 2. We end up storing a lot of images in Cloudinary which will get expensive. We can end up deleting about 90% of the images we save
>      immediately after this process, because the user is only going to
>      select one of the images that appear in the browser, but we are
>      worried about the costs that might be incurred even if the images
>      reside on Cloudinary for a few seconds.

Does anyone have an experience with these problems and think they have a better solution than the one we are using?

Comment: Why does the client have to request images via Ajax?  There are no cross-origin restrictions on loading of an image via an `<img>` tag if you just want to display it in a web page.

Comment: ahh very interesting...so we could dynamically insert img tags into our front-end html given the list of urls sent from our server, and this would load a preview of the images..is that right?

Comment: I am not really a front end dev so I don't really know much about this!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Your server can supply the URLs to the front-end.  The front-end, can then just insert `<img>` tags with the right URL in them and they will display in the page no matter what origin they are from.  I put this comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it seems like it might be a solution for you.

You can have the server scrape the image URLs from the pages, then send a list of URLs to the client.  The client can then dynamically insert `<img>` tags into the current page with those URLs and the browser will display the images.

There are no cross-origin restrictions on `<img>` tag URLs.

Doing it this way, there is no need to try to download the images with Ajax from the client and thus no CORS issues.  Your server does the cross origin scraping.  Then the client just inserts `<img>` tags with the scraped URLs in them.

---

This technique "borrows" the images from some other site and then uses their bandwidth to display them in your page.  You should likely make sure this is a permitted use of those images.

Comment: after some research, there still seem to be some cross-origin restrictions if I use var img = new Image(); img.src ="http://example.com" img.onload=function(){}; ....should there be any more restrictions on the above than using an actual img tag?

Comment: @AlexMills - As it says in my answer "There are no cross-origin restrictions on `<img>` tag URLs." as enforced by the browser.   The site supplying the images could require certain things on the request (such as auth cookies) or a certain referrer.  If you're having troubles making this work, we'd have to examine the exact URLs to offer any more insight into that.

Comment: yeah I see huh got it

Comment: any idea if using iframes and sending the image from the iframe to the main thread would have any more luck possibly?

Comment: @AlexMills - I don't understand what problem you're still trying to solve.  If you have img URLs that don't work when cross origin, then please post one of the URLs so we can take a look at what the server is returning and also please post a link to the page where the image does work so we can see a request that does work.  The answer lies in what is different between those two circumstances and analysis of the actual requests and responses can yield clues.

Answer (score 1):

Return the scraped list of images to your client, and then use your nodejs server as a proxy to serve those images.

Here's a quick example using the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module:

```
http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
  var x = request('http://example.com/image.png')
  req.pipe(x)
  x.pipe(resp)
})
```

Your client would then have access to any desired image:

```
domain.com/proxy?url=http://example.com/image.png
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't this put significant load on a node.js server?

Comment: also probably just need to do request(url).pipe(res).

Comment: Yep. You might want to consider having a separate proxy server from your main webserver.

Comment: thanks this might be a solution - do you happen to know why a proxy server can access content from other servers but the front-end can't? is it just the rules for XmlHttpRequest? is there a way around it?

Comment: The best way I can explain it is that browsers just decided to play nice by preventing requests to servers that don't explicitly grant them permission (there's no way around this if CORS headers aren't set on the preflight response). There's no reason why you can't make that same request using some script that you write, or in your case a proxy server.